# Signing a jar with jarsigner using a PFX file

Tags: code-signing, pki, jarsigner

What I've done is the following:

1. Creating a `ca.key` and `ca.cert`
2. Creating a `server.key` and `server.csr`
3. Signing the CSR with the CA, creating a `server.cert`
4. Creating a `pfx` using the `server.cert` and `server.key`

All this using OpenSSL.

Now I want to sign a JAR file with this PFX file using jarsigner.

`$ jarsigner -storetype pkcs12 -keystore certificate.pfx myJAR.jar my-alias`

And I get:

```
jar signed.

Warning:
The signer's certificate chain is invalid. Reason: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2022-05-12) or after any future revocation date.

The signer certificate will expire on 2022-05-12.
```

I also get this when I verify the jar. I'm guessing that this is due to the fact that nothing tells the JRE to trust the CA that signed the certificate that signed this JAR, but I'm not sure. What is a certificate chain anyway?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

An X.509 certificate can be used for various purposes. The `keyUsage` and `extendedKeyUsage` extensions in the certificate identify what its intended uses are. When a certificate is issued with certain keyUsage's, you can only perform those cipher operations with its public key. If you are trying to do any other operation that is not supported, the library that is doing the cipher operation will complain so. You can find the standard key usages [here](https://help.hcltechsw.com/domino/11.0.0/admin/conf_keyusageextensionsandextendedkeyusage_r.html).

A certificate that is to be used for code-signing purposes **should** contain the `digitalSignature` key usage. You can read more about this [here](https://www.globalsign.com/en/code-signing-certificate/what-is-code-signing-certificate#:%7E:text=A%20Code%20Signing%20Certificate%20is,to%20a%20private%20key%20pair.).

So in your case, it is either one of these:

1. You didn't ask the CA to issue the certificate with `digitalSignature` keyUsage, (or)
2. If you see `digitalSignature` keyUsage added, then the CA is not configured properly to issue the digital signature certificate (probably missed to add the necessary attributes required).

If you are using a well-known CA, then you don't have to worry about the point (2), it will be taken care of and you can focus on point (1).

There are two ways to do that, if the CA is honoring the extensions from your CSR, then you need to add the `digitalSignature` extension in the keyUsage of your CSR (or) if the CA isn't honoring the extensions from your CSR, then you need to figure out how to ask the CA for a digitalSignature certificate.

Answer (score 0):

A certificate is simply a trusting relation between two entities, the issuer (who sign on the certificate) and the subject.

Example:

```
Gov. of Merryland (Issuer) (Root-CA) 
 + certificateA
   + Tot The Diplomatist (Subject)
     + certificateB (contains copy of certificateA in a chain)
       + Dot The Diplomatists Secretary
```

So we have a certificate chain. (Id painted this as a tree because on a certificate can theoretically be signed by multiple issuers).

Each certificates have the signature of one Issuer in this example:

- The issuer of CertificateA is the Gov. of Merryland.
- The issuer of CertificateB is Tot The Diplomatist.

Now assuming the Diplomatists Secretary arrives in Oogaboo showing its CertificateB (Having the CertificateA in the "Chain"). The Government of Oogaboo try to verify the authenticy of the Secretary using the "Chain" of the certificates.

What the message

> unable to find valid certification path to requested target

sais is that Gov. of Oogaboo do not trust any of the Issuers.

Comment: In your example, is CertificateB signed by CertificateA ?

Comment: In your analogy to the Gov. of OOgaboo, the `unable to find valid certification...` comes in the phase of the validation of the certificate. Why do I get this warning when signing the file ?

Comment: @YoavKlein You get the message because Oogaboo do not trust any of the Issuers. Oogaboo neither trust Dot nor Tot nor Gov of Merryland. Assuming you need to run the jar in a browser, the browser have a built-in list of RootCAs. None of the issuers is in this list of RootCAs and the browser will reject the usage of the jar. Because you do no know at the moment of signing the jar that a Browser will reject the jar you get this warning.